# Upload file to a REST API using fetch in native NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, fetch

I'm trying to use the native fetch() API in NodeJS to upload a file to a REST API.
So far, I've made other GET and POST requests successfully, but this file upload is causing me a lot of trouble.

I have the following function -

```js
async function uploadDocumentToHub(hub_entity_id, document_path) {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("type", "Document");
  formData.append("name", "ap_test_document.pdf");
  formData.append("file", fs.createReadStream("ap_test_document.pdf"));
  formData.append("entity_object_id", hub_entity_id);

  const form_headers = {
    Authorization: auth_code,
    ...formData.getHeaders(),
  };

  console.log(
    `Uploading document ap_test_document.pdf to hub (${hub_entity_id}) `
  );
  console.log(formData);

  let raw_response = await fetch(urls.attachments, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: form_headers,
    body: formData,
  });
  
  console.log(raw_response);
}
```

which I then run with the following code -

```js
async function async_main() {
  ......
.......
  await uploadDocumentToHub(hub_entity_id, document_path);
}

// main();
async_main();
```

And I keep getting the following error -

```bash
node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5536
          p.reject(Object.assign(new TypeError("fetch failed"), { cause: response.error }));
                                 ^

TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.processResponse (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5536:34)
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5858:42
    at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:202:9)
    at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  cause: TypeError: object2 is not iterable
      at action (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1660:39)
      at action.next (<anonymous>)
      at Object.pull (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1708:52)
      at ensureIsPromise (node:internal/webstreams/util:172:19)
      at readableStreamDefaultControllerCallPullIfNeeded (node:internal/webstreams/readablestream:1884:5)
      at node:internal/webstreams/readablestream:1974:7
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
}
```

I'm baffled about what's going on and what this error is about. Any ideas?
The following code correctly uploads the file (auto-generated from postman, some data <removed> for security) -

```js
var axios = require('axios');
var FormData = require('form-data');
var fs = require('fs');
var data = new FormData();
data.append('type', 'Document');
data.append('name', 'ap_test_document.pdf');
data.append('file', fs.createReadStream('kX3bdHb1G/ap_test_document.pdf'));
data.append('entity_object_id', '<id>');

var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: '<url>',
  headers: { 
    'Authorization': '<token>', 
    ...data.getHeaders()
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Some help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Undici's (https://www.npmjs.com/package/undici) version of the fetch API (which is what the node developers decided to use) is still experimental and not yet ready for production. You could be just triggering a bug. I'd wait until they take it out of experimental status to use the built-in fetch. Note that undici is a mature and well tested library but it's API is very different from `fetch()`. It's implementation of the fetch API is new

Comment: @slebetman yeah fair enough. I wasn't sure if I was running into a bug as you suggested or an issue of my own devising. For now, I might just stick with the axios implementation (unless I can find a solution). Cheers.

Comment: If you're not stuck on using the fetch API undici is very good. I've been using it in my projects lately replacing the venerable `request` library which is deprecated and no longer supported. Undici is really fast. In my tests it is roughly 10x faster than node-fetch. Where with node-fetch I was getting around 1-2k requests/second with undici I got around 15k requests per second (which I needed because I was writing a stress tester)

Answer (score 2):

You can append a file to the Node 18 native Fetch by reading the file with `fs.readFile` and converting the contents to a `Blob`.

The following is some pseudo-code I whipped up in TypeScript (YMMV):

```
import fs from 'fs/promises';

async function createBlobFromFile(path: string): Promise<Blob> {
    const file = await fs.readFile(path);
    return new Blob([file]);
}

const path = '/path/to/file.txt';
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', await createBlobFromFile(path), 'file.txt');

const response = await fetch('https://some.url', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
});
```

Answer (score -4):

You can't use the `fetch` API in Node.js, either you can install `axios` or `node-fetch`.

````js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const body = {a: 1};

const response = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
});
const data = await response.json();

console.log(data);```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch
https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios
````

Comment: hey I think you can. see - https://blog.logrocket.com/fetch-api-node-js/, https://nodejs.org/ko/blog/release/v17.5.0/

Comment: Could you show the URL of your API?

Comment: i'm trying to post to the following URL - https://api.assetpanda.com:443/v2/attachments

Comment: Try appending `https` instead of `http`

Comment: Please try to catch that error using `try catch`. and paste a screenshot of the browser's network tab with the error you get! I want to see the response from the backend