# Exadel CompreFace - NodeJS FETCH POST not working

Tags: node.js, fetch-api, compreface

I'm trying to post an image from a nodejs app with FETCH API, but not having much luck.

The "CURL" post works fine. Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong? I've tried a few different approaches, see below.

CURL Request (works perfectly) -

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/recognition/recognize?face_plugins=landmarks,gender,age,pose" \
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
-H "x-api-key: <API_KEY>" \
-F "file=@<IMAGE_PATH>/monkey-mania.png"
```

Blob Approach -

```
const {readFile} = require('node:fs/promises');

const url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/recognition/recognize?face_plugins=landmarks,gender,age,pose';

const formData = new FormData();

const blob = new Blob([await readFile('<IMAGE_PATH>/monkey-mania.png')]);

formData.append('file', blob, 'monkey-mania.png');

const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'x-api-key': '<API_KEY>'
  },
  body: formData
};

const fetchResponse = await fetch(url, options);
```

File Path Approach -

```
const {readFile} = require('node:fs/promises');

const url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/recognition/recognize?face_plugins=landmarks,gender,age,pose';

const formData = new FormData();

// with and witjout readFile
const file = await readFile('<IMAGE_PATH>/monkey-mania.png');

formData.append('file', file);

const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'x-api-key': '<API_KEY>'
  },
  body: formData
};

const fetchResponse = await fetch(url, options);
```

Error -

```
Response {
  [Symbol(realm)]: null,
  [Symbol(state)]: {
    aborted: false,
    rangeRequested: false,
    timingAllowPassed: true,
    requestIncludesCredentials: true,
    type: 'default',
    status: 400,
    timingInfo: {
      startTime: 8472.788917064667,
      redirectStartTime: 0,
      redirectEndTime: 0,
      postRedirectStartTime: 8472.788917064667,
      finalServiceWorkerStartTime: 0,
      finalNetworkResponseStartTime: 0,
      finalNetworkRequestStartTime: 0,
      endTime: 0,
      encodedBodySize: 72,
      decodedBodySize: 72,
      finalConnectionTimingInfo: null
    },
    cacheState: '',
    statusText: '',
    headersList: HeadersList {
      cookies: null,
      [Symbol(headers map)]: [Map],
      [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
    },
    urlList: [ [URL] ],
    body: { stream: undefined }
  },
  [Symbol(headers)]: HeadersList {
    cookies: null,
    [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(8) {
      'server' => [Object],
      'date' => [Object],
      'content-type' => [Object],
      'transfer-encoding' => [Object],
      'connection' => [Object],
      'access-control-allow-origin' => [Object],
      'access-control-allow-methods' => [Object],
      'access-control-allow-headers' => [Object]
    },
    [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
  }
}
photo?? { message: 'Something went wrong, please try again', code: 0 }
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/73930210/740553 help?

Comment: Thanks mate. That's where i got the blob example from, but unfortunately no dice.

Comment: Where is this error coming from though? Because this doesn't look like a regular stack trace.

Comment: It's coming from compreface endpoint which works fine with the CURL request - 

http://localhost:8000/api/v1/recognition/recognize?face_plugins=landmarks,gender,age,pose

Comment: I must be doing something wrong on my fetch request structure, don't know what that is though...

Comment: No I mean "can you update your post to show the true stack trace in addition to what's already there" =)

Comment: Hey Mike, Apologies for the late reply. Got caught up with other work, but see working version below.

Comment: Fetch has a lot of options that can be set, so if it works with axios, it will also work with fetch but you didn't set the right option, which is why the actual error and stack trace are so important.

Comment: Which option are you referring to? As mentioned below, i tried the below-working version with fetch and axios using the same options, but fetch didn't work.

Comment: There is no such thing as "didn't work", there is only "did X instead of what I expected" and that's why you need to _show the actual error fetch generates_ (i.e. put `const fetchResponse = await fetch(url, options);` in a try/catch and make the catch log the error object and show _that_ in your post so we see the true error). Because that's going to tell us what you forgot to do. (For instance, axios has laxer security enforcement than the fetch API, so it's entirely possible you forgot a single header that _should_ have been used, but wasn't)

Answer (score 0):

Got it working using "axios" at the end. I tried the same format with #fetch but there seems to be a limitation/bug on the fetch itself. See working code below.

Tested both "fetch" and "axios" methods with the following node versions -

- v18.16.0
- v20.6.0

```
      const imageStream   = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/public/uploads/' + <FILE_NAME>);
      const imageFilePath =  __dirname + '/public/uploads/' + <FILE_NAME>;
      const formData      = new FormData();

      formData.append('file', imageStream, {
        filename: imageFilePath,
        contentType: 'image/png',
      });
      
      const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'x-api-key': '<API_KEY>'
        },
        data: formData
      };

      const res = await axios(options);
```